# Search for particular value under all nodes in a directory

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am struggling to figure out how to delete/look for a certain key/id under any given node in a particular directory.

Here is how my database looks:

[image: this image]

The `userID` and `postID` is generated through the use of `.childByAutoId()`. So as you can infer, searching by a particular string .e.g. a username, is not possible. However, I do have the `postID` passed through the parameters, when calling the function. I have tried several methods, but no luck. In essence this is what I wish to do (pseudo code):

- Go to the "feed" directory
- The postID is passed already, so look through every node under feed
- If the postID exists under a particular node, remove the node, if not, move onto the next node
- Continue until the node does not exist in this particular directory

I do have a reference to my feed directory - `API.Feed.REF_FEED`. I have tried to use `.parent` , `.queryOrdered`, `.queryEqualTo` etc.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
let query = feedRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "-L....VJ").equalTo(true)
query.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) -> Void in
  snapshot.ref.removeValue()
})
```

The problem with this approach though it that it requires that you have an index on `-L....VJ`, and thus on every post ID that you might want to delete. This rapidly becomes unmanageable.

For this reason consider adding an inverted lookup map to your database: one that maps each post ID to the users that have that post in their feed:

```
userposts
  $postid
    userid1: true
    userid2: true
```

Now you can quickly find all the users that have a specific post, and then delete the post from those users' feed.